# Error : Unable to load DLL 'libgmp-10.dll' when testing azure function c# .net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I published my c# .NET 5.0 code to azure functions (windows) and im getting this weird error message:

```
2021-06-21T01:56:53.465 [Error] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=fdefdbba-49a7-44ad-8082-841d2941d90b, Duration=169ms)Unable to load DLL 'libgmp-10.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
```

[image]

I tried to see the \wwwroot files on the azure functions console but then i get this error:

```
 3 [main] ls (8392) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe: *** fatal error - Couldn't set directory to \\?\PIPE\ temporarily.
```

Any hints?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the deployment is not done correctly.

> [Libgmp-10.dll](https://wikidll.com/other/libgmp-10-dll) a DLL (Dynamic Link Library) file which is referred to
> essential system files of the Windows OS. It usually contains a set of
> procedures and driver functions, which may be applied by Windows.

Please delete the Azure Function and, re-create and deploy a fresh code using [Develop and publish .NET 5 functions using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs#prerequisites) OR if you are using ADO, [Setting up a CI/CD pipeline for Azure Functions](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/).

Let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: I tried this solution, did'nt work, im not using ADO, any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing zip deployment or web?

Comment: I'm publishing the code from visual studio 2019, so i guess thats zip deployment